# Load more like facebook or old twitter using php-mysql-html [No jQuery]

Tags: html, css, ajax

I would like to get a tutorial to implement pagination similar to twitter and facebook where it loads a list of items and then below there is a load more button. When this button is clicked the list is appended with a list of items. Can anyone help? Please no jquery

Comment: Can you use JavaScript? This won't work like Twitter/Facebook if you're only using PHP, MySQL, and HTML.

Comment: yes I can use Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you have stated no jQuery, but you're still going to have to make some sort of Javascript call for the AJAX...

[Here is a simple tutorial on how to make one](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/12/twitter-style-load-more-results-with.html), like I said, it uses jQuery but it's only to make the AJAX call which can be changed to normal Javascript if you really need it to. To learn how to do this you can read [this article here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Here it is in two options:

http://blog.hycus.com/2011/03/16/load-more-like-facebook-or-old-twitter-using-php-mysql-jquery/

or a plugin for Wordpress that can be stand-alone as well:

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/